# ¿Cómo mostrar mensajes por pantalla en un ejercicio de drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día chic@s, estoy haciendo un ejercicio de drag and drop sobre canecas de reciclaje. He puesto 3 canecas y 3 residuos, y logro que los residuos entren en cada caneca. El problema es que no sé de qué manera mostrar por pantalla los siguientes mensajes: "Residuo correcto" (en caso de que el residuo que se arrastre y pertenezca a esa caneca), "Residuo incorrecto" (en caso de que no pertenezca). 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<center><h1> Arrastrar y soltar </h1></center>

<center class="caneca">
    <div>
      <p> Caneca azul </p>
      <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca verde </p>
          <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca gris </p>
      <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px">
      </div> 
     </div>
</center>
    <br /> <br />

<center><div id="x">
<img src="imagenes/botella.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="y">
<img src="imagenes/carton.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="70">
</div>

<div id="z">
<img src="imagenes/aluminio.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="88" height="70">
```

Comment: Sería bueno que subieras tus imágenes a algún lado para que coloques los links en los atributos src y poder desarrollar de mejor manera el ejercicio.

Comment: Dame unos minutos amigo, ya lo haré.

Comment: No pude hacerlo, subí una imagen en una página llamada imgBB y luego puse el link en src y no detectó la imagen.

Comment: Bueno no hay problema, ya te hice un ejemplo, igual lo importante es que entiendas la lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que se debe hacer el crear un atributo tanto para los `drag` como para los `drop` para categorizar los colores de las canecas, luego de esto capturamos ambos colores y comparamos, en caso de que el color del elemento `drag` sea igual al color del elemento `drop` entonces es por que el residuo pertenece a la caneca:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    
    var color = ev.target.getAttribute('color');
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("color", color);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    
    var color_drag = ev.dataTransfer.getData("color");
    var color_drop = ev.target.getAttribute('color');
    
    if(color_drag == color_drop){
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); 
      
      alert('Residuo correcto');
    }else{
      alert('Residuo incorrecto');
    }
}
```

```css
.caneca > div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<center><h1> Arrastrar y soltar </h1></center>

<center class="caneca">
    <div>
      <p> Caneca azul </p>
      <div class="img" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="imagenes/azul.png" width="100px" height="90px" color="azul">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca verde </p>
          <div class="img" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          <img src="imagenes/verde.png" width="100px" height="90px" color="verde">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <p> Caneca gris </p>
      <div class="img" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="imagenes/gris.png" width="100px" height="90px" color="gris">
      </div> 
     </div>
</center>
    <br /> <br />

<center><div id="x">
<img src="imagenes/botella.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="70" color="azul">
</div>

<div id="y">
<img src="imagenes/carton.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="70" color="verde">
</div>

<div id="z">
<img src="imagenes/aluminio.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="88" height="70" color="gris">
```

Comment: El único residuo admitido es la botella en la caneca azul, en las demás a pesar de ser el residuo correcto, me marca incorrecto

Comment: @JorgeHernández estás seguro que copiaste el código bien? en el snippet funciona

Comment: Lo había copiado mal, gracias por la ayuda en mis 2 publicaciones, te lo a agradezco de todo corazón, quizá ya debería saber hacer esto, pero hace 2 días empecé con javascript y lo de las funciones no me ha quedado claro, por el hecho de que donde estudio programación solo nos ponen diapositivas y buscar en google para defendernos.

Comment: @JorgeHernández no hay problema acá estamos para ayudar, si necesitas mas ayuda no dudes en preguntar, también puedes darte un pasón por el [chat] allá me encontrarás a mi o a otras personas que estarán dispuestas a ayudar, ahora te invito a marcar la respuesta como aceptada si fue la solución a tu problema, saludos.